# C++ TicTacToe problems

Tags: c++, boolean, void

I am trying to learn C++ and I have made litte tictactoe game but somethings wrong. I've tried to make the winner class both a void and a bool. But when I type in one coordinate it preforms the class. For making it simple you can only win if the 3 on top is O. Whats wrong?
SO if I input: 0 0 it says winner

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

const int rows = 3;
const int elements = 3;

const char Ochar = 'O';

char board[rows][elements];

void Clear()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < elements; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void Show()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < elements; j++)
        {
            std::cout << " " << board[i][j] << " |";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "------------" << std::endl;
    }
}

bool PlayerAttack(int x, int y)
{
    if (board[x][y] == 0)
    {
        board[x][y] = Ochar;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void Winner()
{
    if (board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2] = 'O')
    {
        std::cout << "Winner";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Clear();
    Show();
    int pos1 = 0;
    int pos2 = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "Please input a coordinate: "; std::cin >> pos1 >> pos2; std::cout <<     std::endl;
        PlayerAttack(pos1, pos2);
        Show();
        Winner();
    }
}
```

Comment: They are called functions, not classes (Clear, Show, ...).

Comment: `if (board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2] = 'O')` That's a blatant misconception! Read about the c++ [comparison](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) and  [comma](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) operators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line does not do what you think it does

```
if (board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2] = 'O')
```

You'd have to do

```
if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[0][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O')
```

To use your `Winner` function to break your loop

```
bool Winner()
{
    // You'll obviously have to check more than just this row
    if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[0][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O')
    {
        std::cout << "Winner";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in `main`

```
int main()
{
    Clear();
    Show();
    int pos1 = 0;
    int pos2 = 0;
    bool winner = false;
    while (!winner)
    {
        std::cout << "Please input a coordinate: "; std::cin >> pos1 >> pos2; std::cout <<     std::endl;
        PlayerAttack(pos1, pos2);
        Show();
        winner = Winner(); // Use the returned bool
    }
}
```

Comment: But when I win I want to break out from the loop how do I do that?

Comment: That code would evaluate the expressions board[0][0], and board[0][1] and board[0][2] sequentially, ignore the value of the first 2 (comma operator), and assign 'O' to board[0][2]. (= is the assignment operator, comparison operator would be ==). Comma is rarely used and cannot be used like this.
Then it returns the assigned value 'O'. Because 'O' (aka some ASCII character code) is not zero, the conditionnal is true and it enters the block, and prints "Winner".